# Where can I find free horror-themed stock audio for zombie campaigns?

Tags: gm-preparation, horror, zombies, sound-effects

Does anyone know where I can find free stock audio to enhance my campaign? I am working of my first zombie RPG and all the places I normally go for stock sounds don't have any horror stuff.

I'm  looking for zombie growls, and other creepy ambience, and audio cues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bunch on SoundBible:
http://soundbible.com/tags-zombie.html

AudioBlocks also has some nice ones, and the site shows you a graph of each clip:
http://www.audioblocks.com/search/?srch-term=zombie&srch-type=sfx

I'd also recommend checking out the "horror sounds", which includes various ambient sound effects popular in horror films, and a few screams and creaky doors:
http://soundbible.com/tags-horror.html

Comment: that was exactly what I was looking for thank you